# onload Functions Firing Out Of Order

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Any idea why the following code:

```
    <script>        
        var access_token;
        var access_token_secret;        

        function Login(){
            img = document.getElementById('authenticate');
            img.src = 'authenticate.png';
            login = document.getElementById('login');
            login.style.visibility="visible";
        }
        function cookieHandlerStep1(){
            chrome.cookies.get({ 
                url:URL_GOES_HERE, 
                name:'access_token'
            },
            function(cookie){
                if(cookie){ 
                    access_token = cookie['value'];
                    cookieHandlerStep2();
                } else{ 
                    Login();
                }
            });
        }
        function cookieHandlerStep2(){
            chrome.cookies.get({ 
                url:URL_GOES_HERE, 
                name:'access_token_secret'
            },
            function(cookie){
                if(cookie){ 
                    access_token_secret = cookie['value'];
                    Interact();
                } else{ 
                    Login();
                }
            });
        }
        function Interact(){
            alert(access_token);
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", URL_GOES_HERE, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    document.write(xhr.responseText);
              }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>


<body onload="cookieHandlerStep1(),cookieHandlerStep2(),Interact()">
```

Could possibly have the functions executing out of sequence?

Answer (score 2):

They're not firing out of order. You've provided callbacks to `chrome.cookies.get` which are not guaranteed to be called before the rest of the code. The first function returns before the callbacks are fired, and the next two (`cookieHandlerStep2()` and `Interact()`) get called.

However, in these callbacks, `cookieHandlerStep1()` is already calling `cookieHandlerStep2()` which then calls `Interact()` - so I presume what you actually want in your `onload` is just the first function to initiate the chain:

```
<body onload="cookieHandlerStep1()">
```

Comment: This is very helpful.
I did, however, forget to edit the code fully. 
CookieHandlerStep1 in the up-to-date code doesn't fire CookieHandlerStep2. Nor does CookieHandlerStep2 fire Interact().

I think the important think you said is that the callbacks aren't guaranteed to be called before the rest of the code.

What was happening to me (before I edited each function to call the next function in the chain), was Interact() was firing, then CookieHandlerStep1(), and finally CookieHandlerStep2().

Can you explain a little bit about WHY the callback function doesn't get executed before the next func?